# Sealing jar files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, sealed

How can be jar files sealed using IntelliJ idea?

I believe it is made with jar cmf command, but how can it be achieved in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `jar cmf`. By using `m` you can pass a Manifest file. To seal a jar your manifest file have to contain the line `Sealed: true`. See [Sealing Packages within a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) for details. Have a look at [this blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/) to see how to create a jar with custom manifest in IntelliJ.

Comment: cnf-cmf was a typo, I've fixed it.